# how to make the string type of an array to default settings

Tags: php, arrays

I have a form

Name : (input name="detail[name])...in a form

Address : (input name="detail[address])...in a form

Username : (input name="detail[username])...in a form

Now using php I fetched the data as

```
$values = array();    
$values = array_map('ucwords', $_POST['detail']);
```

Here, $values is an array and the data submitted from the form has been manipulated by changing the first letter of each word into caps ... since I incorporated array_map and ucwords

Now what I wanna do is ... I don't want username to be affected with that ucwords function ... suppose if the user types "heNDriX" as username ... I want the same to be dumped in database ...

So please help me guys

Thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 1):

If you just have one exception, you can just overwrite your values array with the value in $_POST['detail']['username']

```
$values = array();
$values = array_map('ucwords', $_POST['detail']);
$values['username'] = $_POST['detail']['username'];
```

Comment: actually i got an array within an array so ... array_map('ucwords', $string) is not working ... how to apply such for an array within an array